# Display Table with AJAX, select row, display row in other table, save into database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have been given very specific instructions on how to do a certain feature.

On the website Im working on you can create events and edit those. Those events can have guests, which are different from normal members that attend an event.

Every guest has to be invited by a member. So I have a table displaying members and in that very Table I have a picture. When you click on said picture it will display a list of guests, that arent part of the event yet.

[image]

All of this already works, but now comes the part that I am unable to do.

Now the admin needs to be able to select a guest. After a row is clicked it must be taken out of the table and displayed in a seperate HTML Table, in case multiple guests can be chosen.

After that the admin needs to press a submit button, to invite the guest to the event.

Now my explicit questions are:

- How can I make my row selectable? I found [this](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/) but I get the error `TypeError: $(...).selectable is not a function` if I try to use it. Edit: I have also since found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/65JPw/2/). When I use this I dont have any errors in my console, but it still does not work. Could it be that it doesnt recognize my table?
- How can I display the row in a seperate HTML Table? With `$("#row").click(function()` maybe?

I tried doing enough research, to warrant asking such a specific question, so please refrain from saying "just google it". Instead I would be thankful for linking me to the right source! I dont want somebody to do it for me, Id just be thankful for any help! :) I am still very new to jQuery and AJAX.

Here is my jQuery for displaying the table, for context:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#show_guests").click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/widenmoos/administrator/components/com_memberportal/anlassansicht/Gast_Liste.php',
            success: function(data,status)
            {
                createTableByForLoop(data);

            },
            async:   true,
            dataType: 'json'
            }); 

        });
    });

    function createTableByForLoop(data)
    {
        var eTable='<table id="Selectable_Guest_Table"><tr><th>Guest</th>'
        for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
        {
            eTable += "<tr>";
            eTable += "<td>"+data[i][0]+ " " +data[i][1] + ", " +data[i][2]+"</td>";
            eTable += "</tr>";
        }
        eTable +="</table>";
        $('#forTable').html(eTable);
    }
```

Comment: single guest can be chosen easily

Comment: In case of multiple selections, I think you need checkboxes with the specific id of each row

Comment: @ZainFarooq So how would I go about choosing single guests?

Comment: use `this` for that

Comment: @ZainFarooq this? One of the links in my post you mean?

Comment: check this link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_click

Comment: @ZainFarooq what would I use in place of p, in your example? Since the rows in my table arent selectable. How would I let it know, that I want one specific row dissapear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the following code: 
I'm dynamically creating a new table to contain the selected guests. You can then use the same way I'm storing each rows' guest attributes to move parameters and use them whenever you need to send the emails.

```
function createTableByForLoop(data)
{
    var eTable= $("<table  />").attr("id","Selectable_Guest_Table").append(
        $("<tr />").append(
            $("<th />").html("Guest")
        )
    );
    for(var i=0; i<data.length;i++)
    {
        eTable.append(
            // you can store whatever data comes from the js object in this way:
            // (in case you can stringify the entire object and store it as row attribute)
            $("<tr />").attr("data0",data[i][0]).attr("data1",data[i][1]).attr("data2",data[i][2]).append(
                $("<td />").html(data[i][0]+ " " +data[i][1] + ", " +data[i][2])
            ).click(function()
            {
                var data0 = $(this).attr("data0");
                var data1 = $(this).attr("data1");
                var data2 = $(this).attr("data2");
                $("#selected_guests").append(
                    $("<tr />").append(
                        $("<td />").html(data0+" "+data1+" "+data2)
                    )
                );
                // Remove row from original table
                $(this).remove();
            })
        );
    }

    var selectedGuestsTable = $("<table />").attr("id","selected_guests").append(
        $("<tr />").append(
            $("<th />").html("Selected Guest")
        )
    );

    $('#forTable').append(
        eTable,
        selectedGuestsTable
    );
}
```

The best way, by the way, is to pass only the guest id on both tables rows, referring then the entire object from the data array when needed.

Comment: Wow! Im baffled! Thank you so much! I feel like Ive learned a ton just by reading your code. Im so grateful right now! A+ Answer :)

Comment: If you use `$("<div />").` to dynamically inject code, you'll be able to do magic.